# Java garbage collection high IO strategy

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am running a java application with 4GB memory. It's a spring boot rest api application and in each http  request creates 12000 java POJO object as response to request. Because of high pojo lot of garbage collection activity gets triggered after response is sent. As response is large and big, garbage collection is triggered too frequently , which slow down the system. How to avoid frequent garbage collection .
In below screenshot of visual vm you can observe dense area where GC is running . How to make sure GC runs after certain interval and only when specific size of memory is full ,like after 2GB only.
What should be GC strategy for high IO driven java application ?

```
-Xmx3373558K
-Xss1M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=210441
```

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

default garbage collector Java 11 G1
[image]

While running the application for 5 minutes  it pauses 228 times and Average of 42ms and Max of 284ms.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide jvm version and garbage collector ?

Comment: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: default garbage collector Java 11  G1

Comment: Did you try with a higher `MaxDirectMemorySize`?

Comment: -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitialHeapSize=2g -XX:MaxHeapSize=4g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g

Comment: I tried above configuration but still CPU utilization is high because of high GC

Comment: This graph looks very strange. It implies not only having lots of garbage collection operations, but also rapid allocations triggering the gc. Monitoring the allocations to identify the source could help.

Comment: The graph is captured during  api call happening at the rate of 10 request / sec . The response of each api call is 12000 pojo and 3 mb size . Pagination is not an option for the application .

Comment: Enable GC logging with `-Xlog:gc* -Xloggc:gc.log` and then post a section of the log file matching the behavior here.

Comment: I suspect that there won't be a solution to this by tweaking the GC settings.  The root cause seems to be the vast number (and presumably size) of the POJOs ... and probably other classes associated with marshalling them into the the Response stream.  It is just a costly way to do things.  The solution will be to optimize the application code or redesign your web API ... so that they don't generate so much garbage.

Comment: The screen shot is pretty hard to see, but it looks like there's no tenured (survivor) objects at all. So it's thrashing new space. The default algorithm choosing new space size might be keeping everything small because - as far as it's concerned - all is fine.  Every gc is recovering new space to a high percent free.  ~40ms is not bad per collection. (But note the numbers you quote are more than the graphs.) You could try forcing the young generation larger with `-XX:NewSize`.  This should lead to fewer collections, and they shouldn't be longer because reachable objects don't change.